# Need filter design to increase DC motor brush life

Tags: brushed-dc-motor

I have an application which uses 120 VDC 1/4 HP motor and has poor brush life. Presently just using a simple bridge rectifier to convert 120 AC line power to 120 DC. I am wondering if adding something simple like a filter capacitor across the rectifier would help in this regard.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this topic, but this PDF paper was easily found and may help you think about the problem: [DC Motor Brush Life](http://industrialelectricalco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/DC-Motor-Brush-Life-White-Paper.pdf)

Comment: Surely this has nothing to do with the motor being operated at 141% its rated voltage...

Comment: @MattYoung 120 V AC RMS is rectified to the same RMS value. Whether the motor is suitable for operating on rectified raw AC is a different matter.

Comment: @Andyaka - RMS is fine if all you're worried about is I^2R heating, but what about increased arcing due to the higher peak voltage? Wouldn't this have a much greater impact on brush life?

Comment: @Andyaka If you want to get technical, the average of the rectified half sine is only 63% of the peak, so its actually 108V. The peak is still over the motor's rating.

Comment: @MattYoung I'm not trying to argue with you.

Comment: @brhans that is exactly what I alluded to in the 2nd half of my comment.

Comment: Exactly what is the motor driving, what length of time is 'poor' brush life, and what brush life were you expecting?

Comment: the usual cause of rapid brush wear is excessive arcing; load friction, conductive commutator gaps, rough commutators, excess start  torque, rapid/frequent start+stops,

Comment: The application is for driving the wheel of a boat lift. We had very good brush life with a previous manufactures motor. However they discontinued the motor and we forced to find a new supplier. The new motor has poor brush life. When I do a physical comparison of both motors I can see that brushes are smaller by say 20% as is the diameter of the commutator. I have told the manufacture I think that this is what the problem is. They pushed back with the poor quality of our AC. I wanted to reach out to you guys to get your feedback.

Comment: 'good' and 'poor' are not lengths of time. But you can expect ... "A gearmotor used with an unfiltered full wave rectified control (1.6 form factor) will have **about half the brush life** of a gearmotor used with a filtered control (1.0 form factor)." https://gearmotorblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/gearmotors-for-long-life-apps/

Answer (score 2):

Without a capacitor after the bridge rectifier you are actually applying a folded sine-wave to the motor, not a true DC voltage.

[image]

As such the voltage across the motor is changing from zero volts to the peak voltage at twice the line-frequency. Worse the RMS voltage of 120V peaks at 140 * 1.414 = ~170V, which is higher than the rated voltage of the motor.

For proper operation you need to smooth out the DC voltage using a sizable capacitor rated for at least 200V across the output of the rectifier.

[image]

Since the load draws current between the peaks from the regulator the capacitor needs to be large enough to supply that current between them without dropping too much voltage. The size of the capacitor therefor depends on how much current is drawn by the load.

With full-wave rectification, the capacitor must supply current to the regulator for half a cycle (t = 8.3ms @ 60Hz,  t = 10ms @ 50Hz).

As such, the Charge Q (Coulombs) removed from the capacitor is Q=I*t, where I is current and t is time.

You need to limit the droop during that period to some voltage drop, say 10%, or 12V for a 120V.

Since Q is also = C*ΔV, where C is the capacitance and ΔV is the voltage drop as the current flows out.

=> C*ΔV = Q = I*t

Rearranging gives C = I*t/ΔV.

For a 2A power supply, 60Hz, full-wave, where you can tolerate a 12V sag in the filter capacitor voltage without the regulator dropping out of regulation,

C = 2 * 0.008/12 = 0.0053F = 1,333uF

As I mentioned earlier that capacitor needs to be rated for at least a 200V. As such your capacitor will be bulky and will not be cheap.

However, that does not directly correct the fact that you are over-volting the motor.

---

Additionally you should consider adding a snubber circuit across the terminals of your motor. This will reduce EMI from the motor and arcing on the brushes caused by the commutator switching. The values of R&C will depend again on the motor resistance and commutation frequency.

[image]